# iPhone media query does not work but browser resize is good

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I don't know what else I could do but for some reason, the responsive does not work on mobile!

When I resize my browser it works fine but on my iPhone X, there is no change...

I have this already on my `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />`

Here is a snippet of my CSS:

```
//I have this setting for browser resize and it works fine:
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    *Style*
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    *Style*
}
//And here for iPhone but it doesn't work at all 
@media only screen 
    and (min-width: 375px) 
    and (max-height: 812px)
    and (orientation : portrait) {
     *Style*        
}
```

Comment: i think you need @media screen and (max-width: 468px) and (orientation : portrait) 468px it's only an example

Comment: Can you show us the minimal example please